# Audio (MediaPlayer) On an Android (Archos 5 IT)

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, archos

Firstly, what is the filepath for an Archos? I'm trying to get some media/audio to play, and it just won't find it...

```
 public void onClick(View v1) {               
                final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource("ARCHOS5:/Music/manowar.mp3");
                    mp.start();
                    Toast.makeText(Textbox.this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

What is wrong with that code?

Secondly: I can't get audio files in "R.raw.'filename'" to play.

It works perfectly on the emulator, but when I press the play button (a different one) on the Archos, it just crashes.

Comment: Would be a good idea to post the logcat output when you run it on your phone, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`openRawResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)) to access items in `R.raw`. To access the SD card, check out resources like [this post](http://www.blog.droidweb.com/?p=953).

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you so, so so much =] I knew I might be missing some code =] -Testing it shortly...

Comment: Hmmm, how can I use this? -like what context?

Comment: In any Activity/Service/ContentProvider in your package, I guess? Never used it myself, I just knew about those resources.